# what is the difference between template reference variable (#) vs [(ngModel)]?

Tags: angular, angular8

I am reading the tutorials and documentation and I did not understand the concept of `Template reference variables`. We have `NgModel` for two way binding but why do we use `Template reference variables` in Angular?

Comment: A template reference variable is often a reference to a DOM element within a template. It can also be a reference to an Angular component or directive or a web component That means you can easily access the variable anywhere in the template.[Read more here on angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables-var) also this [post](https://itnext.io/working-with-angular-5-template-reference-variable-e5aa59fb9af) is a good one. Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

They are both communication ways in Angular.

Ngmodel is generally used to communication between template inputs( one way or two ways.),

```
<input class="input-box" ([NgModel])]="value">
```

ViewChild or ViewChildren is generally used to communication with custom components. You can also use on native elements with ViewChild if you needed to use jQuery or an external library to actually reference the native element (implementing stripe uses this on native elements). You'll also often come across this in angular libraries like ng-bootstrap or angular material will use these template references for binding components.

```
<custom-component #ref></custom-component>
```

Then in your controller you could define.

```
@ViewChild('ref')public customComponent; 

      or

@ViewChild('nativeRef')public component: ElementRef;
```

Answer (score 1):

**[(ngModel)]** is a two way data binding any data changes to and fro from the frontend or backend will reflect into both parts upon how you are calling them and when. According to control flow statements and function calls.

**template reference variable (#)** is a variable which can be used anywhere in the page to refer to other DOM elements for its value.